# Probability that grows from the first of January until the end of December. How to compute?

Tags: probability

Please suppose that an event called OMEGA has, on the first of January, 1/365 probability.
On the second of January, the probability becomes 2/365.
On the third of January, the probability becomes 3/365.
Assuming that the year has 365 days (and not 366), which is the probability that the event OMEGA:
a) Will succeed at least one time in the first K days of the year;
b) Will succeed exactly one time in the first K days of the year.

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

EDIT: The events are independent.

Comment: a) happens at least one time <=> the opposite of never happens

Comment: Are these events independent?

Comment: Yes, they are.  Edited the question and added this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_{i}$ denote the event that OMEGA is realized on day $i$.

At least once:  $$1-P\left[\text{D}_{1}^{c}\cap\cdots\cap D_{K}^{c}\right]=1-\prod_{i=1}^{K}P\left[D_{i}^{c}\right]=1-\prod_{i=1}^{K}\frac{365-i}{365}=1-365^{-K}\frac{364!}{\left(364-K\right)!}$$

Exactly once and $K<365$: $$\sum_{i=1}^{K}P\left[D_{1}^{c}\cap\cdots\cap D_{i-1}^{c}\cap D_{i}\cap D_{i+1}^{c}\cap\cdots\cap D_{K}^{c}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{K}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{K}\frac{365-j}{365}\right)\times\frac{1}{365-i}=365^{-K}\frac{364!}{\left(364-K\right)!}\sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{1}{365-i}$$

Exactly once and $K=365$: $$P\left[D_{1}^{c}\cap\cdots\cap D_{364}^{c}\right]=365^{-364}364!$$

Answer (score 1):

**Succeeding at least one time in the first K days**

=Not{never succeeding}

$1-\frac{364}{365}\frac{363}{365}...\frac{365-k}{365}=1-\frac{364!}{(364-k)!365^k}$

**Succeeding exactly once in the first K days**

={suceeding only on 1st day} or {suceeding only on 2nd day} or {suceeding only on last day}

$\frac{1}{365}\frac{363}{365}\frac{362}{365}...\frac{365-k}{365} + \frac{364}{365}\frac{1}{365}\frac{362}{365}...\frac{365-k}{365}+\frac{364}{365}\frac{363}{365}\frac{1}{365}...\frac{365-k}{365}=$

$\frac{364}{365}\frac{363}{365}\frac{362}{365}...\frac{365-k}{365}(\frac{1}{364}+\frac{1}{363}+\frac{1}{362}+...+\frac{1}{365-k})$=

$\frac{364!}{(364-k)!365^k}\sum^{364}_{n=365-k}\frac1n$

Comment: typo: the last $\frac{1}{k}$ must be $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @drhab tnx. fixed.